# jQuery dual multiple select combo box

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a function that brings value from 1 combo box to the other.

```
product.bind('click', function() 
        {
            var t = ($(this).hasClass('prevbtn'))? 0 : 1;
            if(t)
            {
                unsel.find('option').each(function()
                {
                    if($(this).is(':selected')) 
                    {
                        jQuery(this).attr('selected',true);
                        var op = sel.find('option:first-child');
                        sel.append($(this));
                    }
                }); 
            } 
            else 
            {
                sel.find('option').each(function()
                {
                    if($(this).is(':selected')) 
                    {
                        jQuery(this).attr('selected',false);
                        unsel.append($(this));
                    }
                });
            }
```

is there any way to pass value from unsel box to sel box without removing from unsel box? what i want to do is people are able to pass as many unsel values into sel box as many as they want to.

many thanks!

Comment: I like the way you use ternary operator there :), you can also use `!` operator.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve or where's the problem with that. The code you've posted shows nothing that would remove anything from anywhere. I do see a syntax error or two, though.

Comment: @undefined I guess that's just a matter of taste because `+!$(...)` works just as well (or not cast to number at all, you're right)

Comment: @JanDvorak sorry i left a chunk out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself with:

```
sel.append($(this).clone());
```

It was simply enough.